# Правописание сокращений

Tags: орфография, сокращения

Как правильно писать сокращения такие как "Мед()институт" и т.д.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложносокращённые слова типа *мединститут* пишутся слитно. См. об этом § 119 полного академического справочника «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации».